# For loop syntax bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

Is there a way we can implement some thing like this in bash script ?

```
pureips="10.3.1.111 10.3.1.112 10.3.1.114";
pureservers="a b c";
for ip,server in $pureips,$pureservers; do
    echo "$server | $ip ";
done
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want this to nest so each server runs against each IP (i.e. run 9 times) you can:

```
for ip in $pureips; do
    for server in $pureservers; do
        echo "$server | $ip "
    done
done
```

If you want to just track each item (eg run 3 times, running the first ip with the first server, the second with the second, etc) you can use an iterator and call the index of the array manually. But that does mean we'll also need to convert the strings into arrays first:

```
read -a pureips <<< "10.3.1.111 10.3.1.112 10.3.1.114"
read -a pureservers <<< "a b c"

for ((i=0; i<=${#pureips[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${pureservers[i]} | ${pureips[i]}"
done
```

Comment: This worked perfect Oli. But there is syntactic error in for loop in the second method. You have missed one curly braces there. This is correct one. `echo "${pureservers[i]} | ${pureips[i]}"`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Good spot, my eyes were still waking up.

Answer (score 0):

To use the syntax (well, almost) you were attempting, you would have to convert your strings into arrays:

```
$ pureips=(10.3.1.111 10.3.1.112 10.3.1.114)
$ pureservers=(a b c)
$ for server in ${pureservers[@]}; do 
    for ip in ${pureips[@]}; do  
        echo "$server | $ip "; 
    done 
done
a | 10.3.1.111 
a | 10.3.1.112 
a | 10.3.1.114 
b | 10.3.1.111 
b | 10.3.1.112 
b | 10.3.1.114 
c | 10.3.1.111 
c | 10.3.1.112 
c | 10.3.1.114
```